# Accessing ASP.Net Core MVC app running on Linux VPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What do I need to look out for to get an **ASP .NET Core MVC** app running on a **Linux VPS** accessible to the outside world?

On the Linux VPS and is running my app like this: `dotnet bin/Release/net5.0/app-name.dll`

All seems well - but I can't access the application at: `http://the-ip-address:port_number` neither on `https://...` here.

All is running fine in the logs. But the application is not accessible just yet.

I am clearly missing something... but I am not sure what.

I am not using a reverse proxy just yet. Although I did try that and there seems to be an issue with the ASP .Net app at this stage.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should set Kestrel Listening IP and Port in `program.cs` configuration as follow:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 webBuilder
                 .UseKestrel()
                 .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:80", "https://0.0.0.0:443")                   
                 .UseStartup<Startup>();
             });
```

`.UseKestrel()` determine you are using kestrel rather than IIS for hosting and running your application.

`.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:80", "https://0.0.0.0:443")` means your VPS serve your application to client via main IP address with Http and Https ports.

You have to open Http and Https Ports in your Linux firewall
check your physical or cloud firewall if any exist.